# orderered list in ie7 not spacing on two digit numbers

Tags: css

I have an ordered list in ie7 and the list-style-type decimal is not allowing space on two digit numbers

E.G 1. blah blah, blah
    12.blah, blah, blah
anyone know of a answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a margin/padding right to the ol li?